# Spring boot REST request timeout

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

In my ApiController I have a method:

```
@GetMapping("/dieter/id/{dieterId}")
public DieterDTO getDieter(@PathVariable int dieterId) {
    return apiService.getDieter(dieterId);
}
```

This method calls getDieter in ApiService class

```
@Override
public DieterDTO getDieter(int dieterId) {
    Dieter dieter = dieterRepository.findOne(dieterId);
    return new DieterDTO(dieter);
}
```

When the user calls /dieter/id/1 it works without a problem. But after a long time like 30 minutes, if the user calls the same link the request waits and times out. I did a Debug on it and noticed that the wait is before  the line

```
Dieter dieter = dieterRepository.findOne(dieterId);
```

How can I mitigate this?

Comment: also i saw that  "abandoned connection cleanup thread" is workin during wait time. what is that for?

Comment: Any exception? Is there a connection timeout set for the db connections?

Comment: no not any exception. it waits. hanged. And also no any timeout setting for mysql connections. just regular settings

Comment: There seems to be a memory leak but with the information provided above, its hard to know where. Can you please post a log file?

Comment: 2017-07-06 13:52:51.363 DEBUG 23105 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin

It waits on this line before the line

2017-07-06 13:52:51.410 DEBUG 23105 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3c0e2c7e]